# How can I Change the content of a Div using a Icon-Bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this Icon-Bar as a Navigation for my webside. It all works fine and now I want to add a function that changes the content of a Div on the Right side of my Icon-Bar so that it shows other Submenues for each Icon. 
I tried out some functions I found on the Internet but non of them did work for me. 
So my question is: How can I change the content of a Div with my Icon-Bar.

```js
function setActiveTab() {
  $(".iconBarItem").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('activeIconBar');
    $(this).addClass('activeIconBar');
  });
};
```

```css
.activeIconBar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-bar" style="float: left; height: 100%; background-color: #1C2336;">
  <div class="activeIconBar iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #51B4C7 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> sada sd a</a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #79AE16 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>asasdasd<asdasd/a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #6DC763 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #0574E7 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #5285BA solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #80BCFB solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FF8402 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FFAE00 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FFDF61 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #B147E9 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: code snippet has error

Comment: Ups sorry. Yes I messed this up. my fault.

Comment: Editet the snipet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just edit the .html with jQuery using .html function and depending on which sidebar item is clicked add different content.
My example just adds the same content + the fa-class of the clicked item.

```js
function setActiveTab() {
  $(".iconBarItem").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('activeIconBar');
    $(this).addClass('activeIconBar');
    var icon = $(this).find('i').attr("class");
    $('#sidebar-content').html( "<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>" + icon)
  });
};
```

```css
.activeIconBar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-bar" style="float: left; height: 100%; background-color: #1C2336;">
  <div class="activeIconBar iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #51B4C7 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> sada sd a</a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #79AE16 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>asasdasd<asdasd/a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #6DC763 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #0574E7 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #5285BA solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #80BCFB solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FF8402 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FFAE00 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #FFDF61 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconBarItem" style="border-left: 2px #B147E9 solid;"><a onclick="setActiveTab()" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='sidebar-content'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Helped me so much.